# How to configure QtCreator to work with C++11?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt-creator

I wrote some project using QtCreator 2.5.1 and Qt 4.8.0. I added to *.pro file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
```

And all compiles and works correct, but IDE still highlights C++11-style pieces of code as wrong. E.g. this string:

```
QVector<int> colwi{100,70,30,40,25,25,25,25,25};
```

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Syntax highlighting is done by QtCreator, if you are running 2.5 or newer, it should work fine. Make sure you are running the newest version

Comment: c++ compiler flags are not related to qtcreator syntax highlight

Comment: It should also be `QVector<int>colwi ={..}`

Comment: Thanks, QVector<int>colwi = {..} helped.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall No, both formats are supported. This works, `QVector<int> colwi = {...}` as is this, `QVector<int> colwi {...}`.

Comment: QtCreator 2.5.2 still marks `template<A<B>>` and variadic syntaxes such as `sizeof...` as errors.

Answer (score 1):

in your qmake .pro file, add

Qt5:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

or Qt4:

```
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

See http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/24551

Answer (score -1):

Partially by upgrading to Qt Creator 2.6. It has better support for C++11 features, but is still not complete. Looking around creator is in good company there: I have not seen any compiler yet that covers all the new features either;-)

Note that Creator does look at the CXXFLAGS your project sets. If you leave -std=c++0x out, then the code model will not make the C++11 features available.